# Grouping not working as expected returning more emails than should

Tags: c#

I have a sales order table with 23 transaction they are assigned to either department 1 or 2 I have looked at the data and its has the right assigns to it based on the cateory name however the problem is in my exucuation of the loop as I am getting 23 emails instead of just 5 sales order emails which is what it should be

Say for Example The table is

```
SalesOrder Number  Depart
 1111              1
 1111              2
 2222              2
 2222              2
```

I should be getting one email for sales order 1111 sent to department 1 and one sent to department 2 but in the 2222 case I should get one email including all 2222

I think the issue is the group by does not no how to batch and I am asking what is the best way of doing that.

```
public void ProcessTransactions(string csvFileName)
{
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<SalesOrderHeader>();
        var SalesOrders = engine.ReadFile(csvFileName);
        var engine2 = new FileHelperEngine<SalesOrdersLines>();

        var OrderLines = engine2.ReadFile(csvFileName);

        GetSalesOrdersForImport();
        ImportTransActions(SalesOrders.ToList());


        CreateSalesOrder(_salesOrders.ToList(), _salesOrders.ToList());


        var groupedSalesOrders = SalesOrders.OrderBy(x => x.SalesOrderNumber)
       .GroupBy(x => x.SalesOrderNumber);

        foreach(var group in groupedSalesOrders)
        {

            foreach (var item in group)
            {

                GetEmailsFromDepartment(item.DepartmentId);
                GetSalesOrdersByDepartment(item.DepartmentId);
                SendEmailNotificationPerDepartments(item.SalesOrderNumber.ToString());
            }        
        }
}
```

My Get Emails for Department function is as below

```
public List<EmailDepartMents> _emailListsByDepartment { get; set; }
public void GetEmailsFromDepartment(string departmentId )
{            

                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];

                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string selectQuery = @"SELECT [Code]
      ,[Name]
      ,[U_DepartmentId] AS DepartmentId
      ,[U_CardCode] as CardCode
      ,[U_Email] As Email
  FROM [NKCoatings].[dbo].[@FIT_DEPARTMENTS]
  where [U_DepartmentId]='" + departmentId +"'";

                    _emailListsByDepartment = connection.Query<EmailDepartMents>(selectQuery).ToList();
                }
            }


}
```

**Edit 2** 
To Show send email function in case there is a issue with it in it self.

public void SendEmailNotificationPerDepartments(List SalesOrders)
   {
       try
         {

```
            SAPbobsCOM.UserTable sboTable = (SAPbobsCOM.UserTable)company.UserTables.Item("DEPARTMENTS");

            SAPbobsCOM.BusinessPartners sboBP = (SAPbobsCOM.BusinessPartners)company.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oBusinessPartners);
            string emailAddressCC = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAddressTo"];

            string body;
            string stmpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpAddress"];
            string EmailUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailUserName"];
            string EmailPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPassword"];
            string SmtpPort = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"];
            MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

            Msg.From = new MailAddress("development@test.com");
            Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            Msg.Subject = "Sales Orders Created in SAP";
            body = "Sales orders has been imported into sap";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (Html.Table table = new Html.Table(sb, id: "some-id"))
            {
                table.StartHead();
                using (var thead = table.AddRow())
                {
                    thead.AddCell("Works Order Number");
                    thead.AddCell("Purchase Order Number");
                    thead.AddCell("Date Required");
                    thead.AddCell("Stock Item Code");
                    thead.AddCell("Stock Item Name");
                    thead.AddCell("Customer");
                }
                table.EndHead();
                table.StartBody();

                foreach (var order in SalesOrders.Where(w=>w.DepartmentId == DepartmentId && w.SalesOrderNumber ==salesOrderId).OrderBy(o=>o.SalesOrderNumber))
                {


                    using (var tr = table.AddRow(classAttributes: "someattributes"))
                    {
                        tr.AddCell(order.WorksOrderNumber, "style:font-bold;");
                        tr.AddCell(order.PurchaseOrderNumber.ToString());
                        tr.AddCell(order.DateRequired.ToString());
                        tr.AddCell(order.ItemCode.ToString());
                        tr.AddCell(order.Description.ToString());
                        if(sboBP.GetByKey(order.CardCode))
                        {
                            sboBP.CardName.ToString();

                        } 


                    }
                }
            }



            foreach (var address in _emailListsByDepartment)
            {
                Msg.To.Add(address.Email);
            }


            foreach (var address in emailAddressCC.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                Msg.CC.Add(address);
            }

            body = body + Environment.NewLine + sb.ToString();
            Msg.Body = body;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(stmpServer);
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailUserName, EmailPassword);
            smtp.Host = stmpServer;
            smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt16(SmtpPort);
            smtp.Send(Msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error has occoured at the send email notification " + ex.ToString());
        }


 }
```

I think i am just having a saturday night black out here but I hope someone can help me out maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The group by function groups by key and dont care about order by for that grouping, so you should get all emails for 1111 and all emails for 2222. The OrderBy function there is only for ordering the values inside that group. What you want could be accomplished by 2 calls of GroupBy.

Comment: can you explain with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look something like this:

```
        var list = new List<Email>()
        {
            new Email() {SalesOrderNumber = 10, Depart = 1},
            new Email() {SalesOrderNumber = 10, Depart = 2},
            new Email() {SalesOrderNumber = 20, Depart = 2},
            new Email() {SalesOrderNumber = 20, Depart = 2},
        };
        var groups = list.GroupBy(e => e.SalesOrderNumber) // sort all emails by SalesOrderNumber
            .Select(g => g.GroupBy(e => e.Depart)) // sort groups by Depart
            .Aggregate((l, r) => l.Concat(r)); // aggregate result to only one collection of groups
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Group of SalesOrderNumber: {group.First().SalesOrderNumber}, Depart: {group.Key}");
            foreach (var email in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(email);
            }
        }
```